# Is it possible to customize query made by active admin route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am having an issue with ActiveAdmin with the ability to enable and disable an "active" attribute on a resource.

The objective is to have an enable/disable column that contains a icon link to do the respective action. I have defined the appropriate member actions and column.

Disable works correctly, it calls a disable instance method that sets item.active to false.  Enable, however, does not.  It fails before it inters the code in the member action because it is looking for a relation where the 'active' attribute is set to true.  This is a problem because, by nature, you are not enabling an inactive item.

I've included the error below, as well as my code:

Is it possible to change the query in ActiveAdmin so that it does not look for 'active'='f'

---

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Admin::ItemsController#enable
>   Couldn't find Item with id=4 [WHERE "items"."m_id" = 2537 AND "items"."active" = 't' AND > (orphaned IS NULL OR orphaned = 'f')]

---

```
member_action :enable, :method => :put do
  if @item.present?
    @item.enable
    message = "'#{@item.term}' was enabled"
  end
  redirect_to admin_movie_item_path, :notice => message
end
```

---

```
column 'Enable/Disable' do |search_term|
  if search_term.active?
    link_to image_tag('icon-cancel.png', :alt => 'Disable'),
      "items/#{search_term.id}/disable",
        :confirm => "Disable '#{search_term.term}'?", :method => :put, :title => 'Disable'
  else
    link_to image_tag('icon-accept.png', :alt => 'Enable'),
      "items/#{search_term.id}/enable",
        :confirm => "Enable '#{search_term.term}'?", :method => :put, :title => 'Enable'
  end
end
```

---

Comment: With the enable member_action do you want to set the item to active?

Comment: Yes, I think all the ActiveAdmin queries can be customized. But in your case the issue may be due to a `default_scope` in your item model. Do you have a default scope set?

Comment: I do have a default_scope; however, removing it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Maybe a gem is adding the scope for you.. a soft delete library perhaps?